# Physical simulation of realistic two-legged skeleton

Tags: physics, simulation, game-physics, physics-engine, bulletphysics

I wish to utilize bullet-physics or similar physical-engine to create a realistic skeleton simulation of human-like body with two legs. That is, create a simulation of "a body" made of round mass on top of two "legs", where each leg is made of 3 solid pieces connected through 3 joints and each joint have some degrees of freedom and a limited movement range in each direction, similar to human hip, knee and ankle.

I aim for a realistic model, and hence it will 'stand' only if all joints are balanced correctly and it will fall otherwise.

Any directions, suggestion or pointers to existing tutorials or resources is appreciated! This looks like an awful lot of work doing from scratch...

Comment: [Rigid body dynamics joints](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7066/520) on Physics.SE has some links that might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on similar code at the moment. My approach is use the Bullet Physics Rag Doll Demo as a starting point. It has a rag doll with body parts connected by joints.

I'm then using the Bullet Physics Dynamic Control Demo to learn to bend the joints. The challenging part at the moment is setting all the parameters.

I suggest you learn how to create two rigid bodies connected by a constraint and then to activate the constraint motor to bend the joint.

The following is some code that I'm working with to learn how rigid bodies and constraints work in Bullet Physics. The code creates two blocks connected by a hinge constraint. The update function bends the hinge constraint slowly over time.

Now that I've got this I'll be going back to the Rag Doll and adjusting the joints.

```
class Simple
{
private:
    btScalar targetAngle;

    btCollisionShape* alphaCollisionShape;
    btCollisionShape* bravoCollisionShape;
    btRigidBody* alphaRigidBody;
    btRigidBody* bravoRigidBody;
    btHingeConstraint* hingeConstraint;

    btDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld;

public:
    ~Simple( void )
    {
    }

    btRigidBody* createRigidBody( btCollisionShape* collisionShape, 
                  btScalar mass, 
                  const btTransform& transform ) const
    {
    // calculate inertia
    btVector3 localInertia( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    collisionShape->calculateLocalInertia( mass, localInertia );    

    // create motion state
    btDefaultMotionState* defaultMotionState 
        = new btDefaultMotionState( transform );

    // create rigid body
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo rigidBodyConstructionInfo( 
        mass, defaultMotionState, collisionShape, localInertia );
    btRigidBody* rigidBody = new btRigidBody( rigidBodyConstructionInfo );      

    return rigidBody;
    }

    void Init( btDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld )
    {
    this->targetAngle = 0.0f;

    this->dynamicsWorld = dynamicsWorld;

    // create collision shapes
    const btVector3 alphaBoxHalfExtents( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f );
    alphaCollisionShape = new btBoxShape( alphaBoxHalfExtents );

    //
    const btVector3 bravoBoxHalfExtents( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f );
    bravoCollisionShape = new btBoxShape( bravoBoxHalfExtents );

    // create alpha rigid body
    const btScalar alphaMass = 10.0f;
    btTransform alphaTransform;
    alphaTransform.setIdentity();
    const btVector3 alphaOrigin( 54.0f, 0.5f, 50.0f );  
    alphaTransform.setOrigin( alphaOrigin );
    alphaRigidBody = createRigidBody( alphaCollisionShape, alphaMass, alphaTransform );
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody( alphaRigidBody );

    // create bravo rigid body
    const btScalar bravoMass = 1.0f;
    btTransform bravoTransform;
    bravoTransform.setIdentity();
    const btVector3 bravoOrigin( 56.0f, 0.5f, 50.0f );  
    bravoTransform.setOrigin( bravoOrigin );
    bravoRigidBody = createRigidBody( bravoCollisionShape, bravoMass, bravoTransform );
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody( bravoRigidBody );

    // create a constraint
    const btVector3 pivotInA( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   
    const btVector3 pivotInB( -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    btVector3 axisInA( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    btVector3 axisInB( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    bool useReferenceFrameA = false;
    hingeConstraint = new btHingeConstraint( 
        *alphaRigidBody,
        *bravoRigidBody,
        pivotInA,
        pivotInB,
        axisInA,
        axisInB,
        useReferenceFrameA );

    // set constraint limit
    const btScalar low = -M_PI;
    const btScalar high = M_PI;
    hingeConstraint->setLimit( low, high );

    // add constraint to the world
    const bool isDisableCollisionsBetweenLinkedBodies = false;
    dynamicsWorld->addConstraint( hingeConstraint, 
                      isDisableCollisionsBetweenLinkedBodies );
    }

    void Update( float deltaTime )
    {
    alphaRigidBody->activate();
    bravoRigidBody->activate();

    bool isEnableMotor = true;
    btScalar maxMotorImpulse = 1.0f; // 1.0f / 8.0f is about the minimum

    hingeConstraint->enableMotor( isEnableMotor );
    hingeConstraint->setMaxMotorImpulse( maxMotorImpulse );

    targetAngle += 0.1f * deltaTime;
    hingeConstraint->setMotorTarget( targetAngle, deltaTime );  
    }

};
```

Comment: I read the link you posted. The problem is that article only describes a rag doll. When something hits the rag doll, the rag doll responds appropriately by falling over realistically.

What you want is a rag doll that can stand by itself. You can do so by following the article and activating the motors that control the constraints (joints).

Comment: Your answer is definitely great. Did you made any progress with the rigid joints constraints?

Comment: @Uri, I've been adding motors to joints. I've been focusing on the right elbow and on solving a series of problems such as motors not working when a joint goes beyond a limit. The elbow joint and motors work well now. Next I'll be applying what I learned to the rest of the body. I write about my work in a series of developer journals. [Developer Journal 114](http://tb-nguyen.blogspot.com/2011/07/developer-journal-114-on-bullet-physics_24.html)

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing the results! Goodluck

Answer (score 6):

Check out the OpenSim project (opensim.stanford.edu), which is heavily used by the biomechanics community to study human movement for, e.g., clinical applications. In OpenSim, the human models are often actuated by muscles, not simply by torques at the joints.

OpenSim is built on top of the Simbody multibody dynamics library. See this example from Simbody to hit the ground running with a model of a humanoid: https://github.com/simbody/simbody/blob/master/Simbody/examples/JaredsDude.cpp.

Comment: This is awesome, is there a paper or something similar with reference to the actual baseline model and what the muscle model is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by baseline model. There are a number of  human models and also a number of muscle models. Here's a list of musculoskeletal models: http://simtk-confluence.stanford.edu:8080/display/OpenSim/Musculoskeletal+Models. Here's a description of one muscle model: http://simtk-confluence.stanford.edu:8080/display/OpenSim/Millard+2012+Muscle+Models

Comment: I see, is it obvious from the `JaredsDude.cpp` code which muscle model is being employed?

Comment: Oh...the two links I just sent you are related to OpenSim, not Simbody. I don't know anything about the muscle model used in JaredsDude.cpp. Muscle modeling is commonly done in OpenSim, not Simbody. The JaredsDude example is more of a toy example.

Answer (score 1):

Just found "Computer Simulation Study of Human Locomotion with a Three-Dimensional Entire-Body Neuro-Musculo-Skeletal Model" by Hase & Yamazaki (2002), which provide

> A model having a three-dimensional entire-body structure and consisting of both the neuronal system and the musculo-skeletal system was proposed to precisely simulate human walking motion. The dynamics of the human body was represented by a 14-rigid-link system and 60 muscular models

Answer (score 0):

Doing from scratch will be hard, no doubt about it. I don't know what your goal is. But you don't have to redesign the wheel. Have you taken a look at the [Unreal Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine)? You might find something to reuse there. Many games are built on the top of this engine.